# Is there any non-experimental way to determine what substances are radioactive?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity

Is there any way to determine if a substance is radioactive and if so, is there any way to determine in what form the radiation will appear, like β- or α-radiation?
For example, if I am making a decay chain, is there any way to determine if the daughter isotope is radioactive without searching for information on the internet (or testing it, of course)?

Comment: Well  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486883/can-quantum-theory-predict-the-radioactive-properties-of-given-element ought to be a duplicate, but doesn't have any answers, but  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177002/can-we-predict-the-half-lives-of-radioactive-isotopes-from-theory is clearly related.