# Is there any simple way to predict beta decay half lives?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, weak-interaction, half-life, fermis-golden-rule

### Question

For nuclides that decay by alpha emission, the Geiger-Nuttall law gives a simple and reasonably accurate estimate of the half-life.  Essentially, one can model the alpha particle as a particle in a "box" – the nucleus – and calculate the probability of tunneling out of the box using basic quantum mechanics.  The result is that the half-life depends exponentially on the decay energy:

$$\ln \lambda \approx a_0 - a_1 \frac{Z}{\sqrt{E}}$$

where $\lambda$ is the half-life, $Z$ is the atomic number, and $E$ is the decay energy.

Is there any similar simple relationship for beta decay?

### Answers that don't work

Beta decay half-lives appear to be very poorly correlated with:

- Decay energy.  Rhenium-187 and lutetium-176 have similar half-lives (about 40 billion years), but lutetium-176 has a decay energy of 1.2 MeV while rhenium-187 has a decay energy of just 2.6 keV.
- Atomic number or number of neutrons.  Cadmium-113 has a half-life of more than 8 quadrillion years, while cadmium-115 has a half-life of just 2 days – even though isotopes 112, 114, and 116 are all stable or have extremely long half-lives.
- Nuclear shell closure.  Even though potassium-40 decays to calcium-40, which has magic numbers of both protons and neutrons, it has a half-life of over a billion years.  Meanwhile, potassium-42 has a half-life of only 12 hours.

In short, beta decay half-lives vary widely, and I don't see any obvious rules to help understand why.  Is there any way of explaining these results without a very complex calculation?

### Review of related Physics.SE questions

The answer to [Does the decay energy of a beta decaying isotope become lower as the half life becomes greater (or vice versa)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363918/does-the-decay-energy-of-a-beta-decaying-isotope-become-lower-as-the-half-life-b) says that:

> That leaves the phase space available to the products as the thing that almost solely determined the lifetime.
>
> In short the phase space available to the interaction depends to a large degree on the total energy and to a much smaller degree on the mass of the recoiling remnant nucleus.
>
> I gave a rather more complete treatment in [another answer about the free neutron lifetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/why-is-the-free-neutron-lifetime-so-long?noredirect=1&lq=1).

However, while the theoretical argument that the phase space should depend strongly on the total energy seems plausible, it doesn't seem to match experimental results very well.  As I noted above, nuclei with similar half-lives often have completely different decay energies, and vice versa.

The most upvoted answer to [Can we predict the half-lives of radioactive isotopes from theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177002/can-we-predict-the-half-lives-of-radioactive-isotopes-from-theory) mentions a

> quantity "$ft$" which convolves the half-life of the decay with the electrical interaction between the emitted electron and the positively-charged daughter nucleus.

It is supposed to vary within a narrow range.  However, I don't understand this description; also, I looked up some tables of $ft$ values and found that $ft$ actually varies by many orders of magnitude between different nuclei.  For example, [this textbook chapter](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/ch374/ch418518/Chapter%208%20Beta%20Decay-rev.pdf) (chapter 8 from *Modern Nuclear Chemistry* by Loveland, Morrissey, and Seaborg) cites $\log(ft)$ values ranging from $-0.27$ to $+7.36$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it is too long.

The alpha particle is a stable nucleus itself, and the decays happen purely from energy considerations: there exists a system with lower energies to which a decay of an alpha gives access.

Beta decay is a two level decay: there should exist a system of nucleons with lower total energy, but also the neutron itself should decay in order to get the beta/electron. It is a two paths decay, the second depending on the weak interaction. That is why a single rule is not possible.

A neutron has a probability to decay within a nucleus, if it is neutron rich, and the neutron's orbital has a probability to be far enough for the residual strong force (the nuclear force) to be weak and when free a neutron decays. This would depend not only on energies, but also on the specific neutron orbitals. Or it could be a simple energy level accessibility consideration and the neutron is freed and decays.